# Aceptar solo registros de email con dominio outlook y hotmail en laravel

Tags: php7, laravel-8, jquery-ui

Cordial saludo.
en el siguiente metodo del controlador RegisterController debo validar si el email es outlook o hotmail.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
 return Validator::make($data), [
  'documento' => ['required', 'string', 'max:40', unique:users],
  'nombre' => ['required', 'string', 'max:40'],
  'apellido' => ['required', 'string', 'max:40'],
  'telefono' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10'],
  'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', unique:users],
 ]),
}
```

que expresión puedo utilizar para validar el dominio del email?

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para hacer lo que pides yo lo haría de esta forma:
Agrega una regla personalizada en la validación del campo email. La regla personalizada compara el dominio del correo electrónico con una lista de dominios permitidos (Outlook y Hotmail). Si el dominio no está en la lista de dominios permitidos, la validación fallará y se mostrará un mensaje de error.

```
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        // Agrega la regla personalizada para el dominio
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'email',
            'max:255',
            'unique:users',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                $allowedDomains = ['outlook.com', 'hotmail.com'];
                $domain = explode('@', $value)[1];
                if (!in_array($domain, $allowedDomains)) {
                    $fail("El dominio del correo electrónico no está permitido.");
                }
            },
        ],
    ]);
```

Espero esta respuesta te sea de ayuda